# Concatenate multiple columns into one in hive

Tags: string, shell, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I need to concatenate column values into a single column.
I have column names in a variable as `colnames=col1,col2,col3` .
I am writing the below query from a unix shell and calling the hive. But when I do this, I am getting only the column names concatenated not the values of those columns.

```
select concat('regexp_replace("${colnames}",",","^")) as result from table;
```

I would like the output as:

> ABCD^10^XYZ

(`ABCD`,`10`,`XYZ` are the column values)

Comment: Can you explain  by providing test data and sample output

Comment: I have columns to be concatenated in a variable like below colnames=col1,col2,col3.  Now I am using the above query in the Unix shell as hive -e "select concat(regexp_replace("${colnames}",",","^")) as result from table" I am getting result as col1^col2^col3 but I want values for the column as ABCD^10^XYZ

Comment: you are giving the same things you explained above

Comment: You have give col1 value and col2 value and so on

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `concat_ws` function to concatenate values with `^` as a delimiter.

Example with constants:

```
hive> select concat_ws('^','ABCD','10', 'XYZ');
OK
ABCD^10^XYZ
```

Command with column names after shell variable substitution should look like this:

```
 select concat_ws('^',col1,col2,col3) as result from table;
```

In the shell it will look like this:

```
colnames=col1,col2,col3
hive -e "select concat_ws('^',${colnames}) as result from table"
```

If columns are not string, wrap them with cast as string using shell, this will allow concat_ws work with strings and not-string columns.

Example

```
colnames=col1,col2,col3
colnames2=$(echo "cast( $colnames as string)" | sed "s/,/ as string), cast( /g")
echo "$colnames2"
```

Output:

```
cast( col1 as string), cast( col2 as string), cast( col3 as string)
```

Use new variable to pass to hive as in the previous example.

Comment: The above works If we give the column names manually, in my case, I do not know the columns to be concatenated, I will get it from the variable(colnames=col1,col2,col3) which is why I am using ${colnames} in place of column names since it is a shell, it will populate the column names there.

Comment: **CONCAT_WS('^',(SPLIT('${colnames}',','))) as result** , This one also gives only the column names concatenated not the values

Comment: @akm Sure, this is not like in my example. Please read the last one. You are using constants, not columns. because SPLIT('${colnames}',',') gives you array of constants, and you need column list in the select statement, not their concateneted names. And select will concatenate values. Do it like in my example pls

Comment: If I simply give **CONCAT_WS('^',${colnames})** then I am getting error - argument of function must be string or array<string>
But I am having data type as char, smallint etc.,

Comment: I will not be able to cast to string also as I will be getting these columns dynamically in a variable and I wont be knowing how many will come and what will be the data type

Comment: I will not be knowing how many columns I will be getting in the variable **colnames**, it is not same always

Comment: then how can I mention columnname and then cast it If I don't know the column name itself

Comment: If you only have a variable with column names, then use shell to create new variable based on first one. Or alternatively you can build a view on top of your table with all columns casted as strings like `select cast(col1 as string) as col1`

Comment: Thank u, I will try that.

Comment: @akm, see updated answer with shell example. Not ideal but works