# How to md5 an entire row in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Using Hive, I want to hash an entire row in the query.

I tried the following (don't mind the ${xxx}, query is built from a bash script):

```
    SELECT md5(*) FROM ${DATABASE_NAME_SUFFIXE}.${DATABASE_PREFIXE}_${TABLE_NAME} WHERE 
${TABLE_DATE_FIELD} <= '${LIMIT_DATE}' ORDER BY ${CREATION_DATE_FIELD} DESC LIMIT 1
```

This returns the following error:

> Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'md5': No matching method for class
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFMd5 with (bigint, int, varchar(128),
>   timestamp, timestamp, varchar(64), varchar(64), varchar(64), int,
>   bigint, int, varchar(50), varchar(255), bigint, timestamp, timestamp,
>   varchar(64), bigint, timestamp, timestamp, varchar(64), int, int,
>   char(38), varchar(40), varchar(1)). Possible choices: *FUNC*(binary) 
>   *FUNC*(string)

If I understand correctly from the error and from the documentation of md5 function, I need to pass binary or string. How can I achieve that ?

Edit: also tried:

```
SELECT md5(SELECT * FROM ${DATABASE_NAME_SUFFIXE}.${DATABASE_PREFIXE}_${TABLE_NAME} WHERE ${TABLE_DATE_FIELD} <= '${LIMIT_DATE}' ORDER BY ${CREATION_DATE_FIELD} DESC LIMIT 1)
```

which returns

> cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' '*' 'FROM' in function
>   specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concat` all the columns and then have **`md5()`** on the concatenated column.

```
select md5(concat(a,b)) as md5 from (select string("abc")a,int("2")b)e;
+--------------------------------+
|md5                             |
+--------------------------------+
|63872b5565b2179bd72ea9c339192543|
+--------------------------------+
```

We can also define [variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51211278/concatenate-multiple-columns-into-one-in-hive/51211672) having all column names then use in `concat` function!

---

**`Try with concat(*):`**

```
select md5(concat(*)) as md5 from (select string("abc")a,int("2")b)e;
+--------------------------------+
|md5                             |
+--------------------------------+
|63872b5565b2179bd72ea9c339192543|
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: There is absolutely no way to do it without specifying all column names ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain try with `concat(*)`!

Comment: Working on it right now. However in the subquery, it seems mandatory to indicate column names. It ads complexity to my query building logic.
For example, this won't work: `SELECT md5(concat(*)) as hash from (SELECT * FROM BATCH WHERE last_modified_time_u <= '' ORDER BY creation_time_u DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: @FlorianCastelain, I was able to run similar query:
**`select md5(concat(*)) from (select * from i where 1=1)e;`** you need to alias subquery.. **`SELECT md5(concat(*)) as hash from (SELECT * FROM BATCH WHERE last_modified_time_u <= '' ORDER BY creation_time_u DESC LIMIT 1)e`**